# How to avoid query inside loop in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have created a simple profit and loss calculation based on FIFO entry in my database of buy and sell order, 
and get the buy orders first then I see the sell orders against them and i get the price difference between them and that my profit but now the problem is I have to get the fresh sell orders for every loop of buy order and my code get stuck when the data is large.

can anyone give me the solution for this?

**Code:**

```php
 //get all buy tx orders
            $pnl_logs = BuyOrder::where('status', 0)->OrderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get()->take(50);
            if ($pnl_logs->isEmpty())
                return Response::json(['code' => 0, 'message' => 'No Record found in buy Order to update']);
            foreach ($pnl_logs as $logs) {

                //get current buy rate  and sell rate from price automation table
                $system_buy_rate = PriceAutomation::where('type', 0)->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->first();
                $system_sell_rate = PriceAutomation::where('type', 1)->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->first();

                //subtract percentage fees from buy orders
                $sell_rate = $this->updateSellRate($logs->vendor_id, $logs->sell_rate, $system_buy_rate->base_rate);

                //get all sell tx orders
                $sell_orders = SellOrders::where('status', 0)->OrderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get()->take(50);
                if ($sell_orders->isEmpty())
                    return Response::json(['code' => 0, 'message' => 'No Record found in Sell Order to update']);
                $sum = 0;
                $data = [];
                foreach ($sell_orders as $key => $orders) {

                    $sum += $orders->remaining_amount;
                    $data[$key]['id'] = $orders->id;
                    $data[$key]['remaining_amount'] = $orders->remaining_amount;
                    $data[$key]['sell_rate'] = $orders->sell_rate * $orders->remaining_amount;
                    $data[$key]['system_sell_rate'] = $system_sell_rate->base_rate * $orders->remaining_amount;
                    $data[$key]['source'] = $orders->gold_source;

                    if ($sum >= $logs->gold_amount) {
                        $status = 0;
                        $rm_balance = 0;
                        $avg = 0;
                        $system_avg = 0;
                        $buy_rm_amount = $logs->gold_amount;

                        foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
                            $buy_rm_amount -= $v['remaining_amount'];
                            if ($buy_rm_amount > 0) {
                                //a sell tx order is completely consumed for buy tx order
                                $avg += $v['sell_rate'];
                                $system_avg += $v['system_sell_rate'];
                                $status = 1;
                            } else {
                                //if buy order is completely satisfied sell tx order
                                $rm_balance = $sum - $logs->gold_amount;
                                $avg += ($v['remaining_amount'] - $rm_balance) * $orders->sell_rate;
                                $system_avg += ($v['remaining_amount'] - $rm_balance) * $system_sell_rate->base_rate;
                                if ($rm_balance == 0) {
                                    $status = 1;
                                } else {
                                    $status = 0;
                                }
                            }

                            //update sell order status
                            SellOrders::where('id', $v['id'])->update(['status' => $status, 'remaining_amount' => $rm_balance, 'system_sell_rate' => $system_sell_rate->base_rate]);
                            //entry in pnl log
                            $pnlLogData = [
                                'tx_id' => $logs->tx_id,
                                'buy_order_amount' => $logs->gold_amount,
                                'sell_order_amount' => $v['remaining_amount'] - $rm_balance,
                                'gold_source' => $v['source']
                            ];
                            PnlLog::create($pnlLogData);
                        }
                        $logs->system_sell_rate = ($logs->system_sell_rate == 0) ? $sell_rate['system_rate'] : $logs->system_sell_rate;
                        $logs->system_buy_rate = $system_avg;
                        $logs->buy_rate = $avg;
                        $logs->sell_rate = $sell_rate['rate'];
                        $logs->status = 1;
                        $logs->save();
                        break;
                    }
```

Comment: You query in three loops, that's really bad, try to build an array in loops and update or insert outside the loop.

Comment: I can't because I have to update the sell orders if they match the buy orders and for the next buy order I need the fresh records which have not matched with buy order based on FIFO.So I am looking to avoid the query inside the loop but how to save the match records and get the next one in next loop